# PHP include doesn't display pictures

Tags: php, include

I have a small problem. I'm not good in php, so this may be something really simple. Basically, I have couple of websites, which I want to implement a specific picture on. I want it to be controlled (along with a hyperlink) from one script. So what I've done is this:

```
   <?php include 'http://content.captive-portal.com/pd/sponsored/sponsored.php' ?>
```

I have placed this code on couple of websites but it doesn't display a picture. Why? Can it be done this way? 
The page I placed this script on is this one:
[amc link](http://amc.captive-portal.com/manchester/menu.html) - the image should appear just underneath a logo. The gif image from the script above. Can anyone please help me out with this? What have I done wrong? can't it be done? THank you for your help.

The code is here:

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <img id="logo" src="images/logotop_m.jpg"/>
        <?php include 'http://content.captive-portal.com/pd/sponsored/sponsored.php' ?>
</div> <!--eo wrapper -->

...
```

Comment: What does the resulting HTML delivered to the browser look like?

Comment: can you explain me why i got downvoted for this???

Comment: Because obviously you didn't take a look at the error log 1st.

Comment: @DainisAbols as I said I'm not good in php, I used firefox console and it didn't show any problems, so I still dont understand the downvote. It also doesn't display any errors in dreamweaver. So again - why downvote? where can i find the error log you are writing about?

Comment: Make a file containing only the line you provided in your original post. See if it works. If yes, try to figure out how it differs from the page where you actually want to integrate it. If not, post the html code which is being generated by this php file. Also make sure `allow_url_include` is enabled in your php.ini. `phpinfo()`will let you check this option.

Comment: I have used the 'include' for google analytics and it was working fine. When I try to use it for implementing an image - it doesn't display it.

Comment: so still dont understand the downvote

Answer (score 0):

Is the relative path causing the issue? Does the sponsored.php file make reference to the image using a complete path? (e.g.... http://content.captive-portal.com/images/.... or just images/...)

Comment: to the complete path. this is what is in this php file: <a href="http://bit.ly/VzF7ds"><img src="http://content.captive-portal.com/pd/sponsored/sponsored.gif" width="480" height="80"></a>

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is that some images are being used via relative links. Here's the logo:

```
<img id="logo" src="images/logotop_m.jpg"/>
```

As it isn't an absolute path with a domain, it'll resolve as the following:

```
http://yourdomain.com/images/logotop_m.jpg
```

Instead of what you're expecting:

```
http://amc.captive-portal.com/images/logotop_m.jpg
```

Edit: Oops

I didn't notice the redirect as I opened it in a new tab - my bad. The php file itself contains this:

```
<p><a href="http://bit.ly/VzF7ds"><img src="http://content.captive-portal.com/pd/sponsored/sponsored.gif" width="480" height="80"></a></p>
```

As it's an absolute path, it *should* be alright.

Comment: This logo thing is not the actual problem, the problem is what's underneath which is the script I placed in the question.

Comment: Sorry for that, I noticed the redirect a bit late. Do you have a link to a "live scenario" where you're including the resource at `http://content.captive-portal.com/pd/sponsored/sponsored.php`? In other words, a test page where we can inspect the output sent to the browser.

Comment: http://amc.captive-portal.com/manchester/menu1.html - this page contains only the script. it should display a picture and it does nothing.

Comment: @PiotrCiszewski: At the top of your script, do the following: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`. That way we'll see if it sparks an error. :)